# What is the syntax for a search query that returns items that link to a given url

Tags: search, fast-search

A user would like functionality in search similar to [Google's link: prefix](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=adv_sitespecific&answer=1734233).  They would like to find 'all documents that link to a given url.' The environment uses FAST, so any SharePoint or FAST search syntax should work, but I'm having trouble finding the exact syntax for this.

Comment: What do you mean by link to? The document contains a link to x, or the document is in the folder/structure x?

Comment: The document contains a link to x.  So, "all pages or documents that contain a link to http://somesite/somepage".  The crawler has to maintain this info to be able to crawl, so it stands to reason it's available somehow...